# How to edit multiple select value fetched from database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, database, codeigniter

i am struggling finding a way to edit **multiple select** value that are fetched from database.

there are 3 tables **Supplier** (supplier_Id, supplier_name, location, etc...), **Material** (material_id, material_name), and **supplier_material** (id, supplier_id, material_id). 
in that relation, supplier  can have multiple materials.

For example, supplier_A has wood and steel materials. i want to change it to just wood or add fiber so then i have 3 materials.. i can fetch and view it in a page with php with **selected** value, but then i cannot alter them or add more.

this is my controller :

```
public function edit_supplier($sup_id) {
    $data['data_material'] = $this->dashboard_model->get_material_list();
    $data['data_location'] = $this->dashboard_model->get_location_list();
    $data['edit_supplier'] = $this->dashboard_model->m_edit_supplier($sup_id);
    $data['main_content'] = 'supplier/edit_supplier';
    $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
}
```

the model :

```
public function m_edit_supplier($sup_id) {
        $this->db->select(
            'a.supplier_id, a.supplier_code, a.owner, a.company, d.location, 
            GROUP_CONCAT(c.material ORDER BY c.material) AS material_list');
        $this->db->from('supplier a');
        $this->db->join('supplier_material b', 'a.supplier_id = b.supplier_id');
        $this->db->join('material c', 'c.material_id = b.material_id');
        $this->db->join('location d', 'd.location_id = a.location_id');
        $this->db->where('a.supplier_id', $sup_id);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query;
    }
```

the view :

```
<?php
foreach($edit_supplier->result() as $sup) :
?>
<!-- Select Material-->
              <div class="form-group">
                <?php echo form_error('material[]'); ?>
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="inputMaterial">Material</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <select id="material" class="ajax-example form-control input-sm" id="inputMaterial" multiple="multiple" name="material[]">
                    <?php 
                      foreach($data_material->result() as $row) :
                        $material = explode(',',  $sup->material_list); 
                    ?>
                    <option
                      value="<?php echo $row->material_id; ?>"
                      <?php foreach($material as $mat) {

                        if($row->material == $mat) {
                          echo  'selected ' . ' style="color:#FFFFFF;background-color:#0078D7;"';
                        }
                      }
                      ?>
                    ><?php echo($row->material) ; ?></option>
                  <?php endforeach; ?>

                </select>
                </div>

              </div>
```

i can view the multiple select dropdown of material with jquery ajax but i don't know how to compare the selected value that are in database.